# What does $#vvv--; do to a hash in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, key

This is the whole script, that for some mysterious to me reason outputs "642"

```
#!usr/bin/perl 
%vvv = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
$#vvv--;
%vvv = reverse %vvv;
print keys %vvv, "\n";
```

Also what does "keys" in the last statement do? Thanks for your time. I am just on hurry I don't have proper time to do my research. So again I appreciate you input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$#vvv-- looks like a comment.  What's happening is the hash, being an even numbered element array, is just being reverse.  So it goes from:

```
%vvv = (
    1 => 2,
    3 => 4,
    5 => 6
);
```

to:

```
%vvv = (
    6 => 5,
    4 => 3,
    2 => 1
);
```

So when the keys are printed, it grabs 642, or the new, current keys of the hash.

Comment: `$#vvv--;` is attempting to reduce the last index of the array `@vvv` which has not been defined, but without [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html), its failure goes unnoticed.

Comment: `$#vvv` is not a comment, but it doesn't have any effect on the hash, either.

Comment: Thanks to you and Sinan for the correction.  I saw the # and immediately thought comment.  My mistake!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed i just removed the comment-like line and got the same result. However, there's a very similar problem with arrays, and there when I removed the same line I got different output. Here's the code.. `#!usr/bin/perl
@vvv = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$#vvv--;
print $vvv[$#vvv], "\n";`

Comment: `$#vvv--` discards the last element of the array `@vvv`.  But there's no connection between the array `@vvv` and the hash `%vvv`

Comment: `pop(@vvv);` is way more efficient than `#$vvv--;`.

Comment: @mad why dont you edit your answer to add this new information?

Answer (score 20):

You should always run scripts with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

If you had, you would have noticed an error:

```
Global symbol "@vvv" requires explicit package name at ...
```

Which means that `$#vvv` refers to the maximum index of the array `@vvv`, not the hash. In perl, `@vvv` and `%vvv` are two separate variables. So `@vvv` has nothing to do with `%vvv`, and that operation is without any use.

What the person who wrote the code might have been thinking of is a way to truncate an array:

```
my @array = 1 .. 6; # 1,2,3,4,5,6 but written as a range
$#array--;          # lower maximum index by 1
print "@array";     # prints "1 2 3 4 5"
```

However, that does not work wish hashes.

And as Friar has explained, [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) is a way to swap hash keys and values around. When used on a string, it reverses the string, e.g. "foobar" -> "raboof", but when used on a list, it reverses it, so `1,2,3,4,5,6` becomes `6,5,4,3,2,1`.